# Sort Array Of Objects by different keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, key

I have an Array of Objects. I have displayed this Array of Objects using a for loop. This for loop has been created inside of a function.

```
let myArray = [
    {objectName: "Object 1"},
    {objectName: "Object 2"},
    {objectName: "Object 3"},
    {objectName: "Object 4"},
    {objectName: "Object 5"},
];
function displayMyArray(arrayName) {
    for (let i of arrayName) {
        let card = document.createElement("div");
        card.classList.add("card", i.category);
        let name = document.createElement("h5");
        name.classList.add("objectName");
        name.innerText = i.objectName.toUpperCase();
        container.appendChild(name);
        card.appendChild(container);
        document.getElementById("divToDisplayObjects").appendChild(card);
    }
}
displayMyArray(myArray);
```

This code works as expected.

I have created a Select Tag in HTML which contains multiple options. If the user clicks one of these options, the objects should be sorted in a paticular way. I have done this using the following code:

```
function sort() {
    let sortByValue = document.getElementById('sort-btn').value; // Get the value of the selected option
    let nameAscending = myArray.sort(// Code to sort the elements);
    if (sortByValue == "name_ascending") {
        document.getElementById("div_to_show_objects").innerHTML = "";
        displayMyArray(nameAscending);
    }
}
let sortByButton = document.getElementById("sort_btn");
sortByButton.addEventListner('change', sort());
```

If I click one of the options in the Select element of my HTML page, the 'div_to_show_objects' clears correctly, which means the correct function was called. However, the new sorted Array is not shown.

Why is this and how could I correct it?

I have looked at multiple different questions on Stack Overflow and have been unable to find an answer. I have also looked at multiple different videos and articles and have been unable to find an answer.

I have also tried adding a return statement to the end of the if statement. However this has not worked:

```
return displayMyArray(nameAscending);
```

When I log the value of 'sortByValue' to the console, it returns the correct result. However, the objects do not change order.

Comment: `displayMyArray` does not actually display the array in the DOM. It just logs it to the console.

Comment: Please show all the relevant code. How are you initially showing the elements?

Comment: *"...not shown"*: You are adding a CSS-class named "hide". Does that mean it will not be visible? What is `container`? Its name suggest something else than that it would be **repeatedly** moved around and become a child of one of the `card` elements. This question needs more work. Please provide code (minimal code) which we can *run* as-is and which reproduces the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (sortByValue = "name_ascending") {
```

I think you meant to use "===" here instead and may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: I had already written that in my program. I had written two equal signs in my program but accidentally wrote 1 equal sign here.

Comment: Even if you quote a part of the question, please quote exactly the same. One, two and three equal signs mean totally different.